# How to save object in Core Data with child object of another custom type?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm using SwiftUI 2.0 to build a simple barber app for iOS.

I have these classes:

```
class Cliente: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    let nome, cognome, dataDiNascita, cellulare: String
    let idAccount: Account
}


class Account: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    let email, password: String
    let idAccountTipologia: AccountTipologia
}


class AccountTipologia: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let nome: String
}
```

The 'Cliente' class holds all informations about User such as name, surname, etc.
The 'Account' class holds all informations about User's login credential such as email and password.
The 'AccountTipologia' class holds all informations about User's account type such as Developer, User or Admin.

This is a JSON representation of Cliente's instance retrieved from database:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "clienteName",
    "cognome": "clienteSurname",
    "dataDiNascita": "1998-09-09T00:00:00.000+00:00",
    "cellulare": "1234567890",
    "idAccount": {
        "id": 26,
        "email": "userEmail@gmail.com",
        "password": "userPassword",
        "idAccountTipologia": {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "Developer"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use Core Data in SwiftUI 2.0 to save an instance of Cliente **after login** but the only type available on Core Data are Integer, String, Boolean, etc... and I'm not able to save Account and AccountTipologia variables as Client's child.

So ... how can I do to correctly save the entire 'Cliente' instance?

Comment: You create 3 entities in your model for Cliente, Account and AccountTipologia with relationships between them or since there seems to be a one-to-one relationship between all of them you create one entity only and add all attributes to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create two different entities and create a `relationship` between them to get to your solution.

I suppose in your case it won't be bi-directional. You need to configure the relation correctly, defining the inverse relation. Refer below link for better understanding

https://medium.com/@aliakhtar_16369/mastering-in-coredata-part-5-relationship-between-entities-in-core-data-b8fea1b50efb